# How come in SSMS 18 the other project and file types don't appear in the New file and new project button but Visual studio 2019 has it?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, ssms, sql-server-data-tools

[SQL Server Management Studio 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUFRZ.png)

[Visual Studio 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C38b6.png)

The image above shows my desktop of the programs.

I installed all the required installments for SSMS 18:

- SQL Server, including: SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) and SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS)•
- SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)
- SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT): is a modern development tool for building SQL Server relational databases, Azure SQL Databases, Analysis Services (AS) data models, Integration Services (IS) packages, and Reporting Services (RS) reports, which comes integrated with Visual Studio.

but I still can not make an analysis services multidimensional and data mining project, Analysis tabular project, etc.

Please someone please tell me what to do to fix this issue? If possible, please tell a better way to install these programs in order for SSMS to have the extensions from Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Because SSDT is just Database projects in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: A quick google of "SSDT Visual Studio 2019" would have lead you to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15), which explains all this; and where and how to create SSRS/SSAS/SSIS projects.

Answer (score 1):

> I still can not make an analysis services multidimensional and data mining project, Analysis tabular project, etc.

These have never been available in SSMS, only in Visual Studio.